# In Vim/NeoVim, how to draw inside text buffer without modifying content

Tags: vim, neovim

For example, suppose I want to implement a plugin that draws a margin line at 80 colums using custom characters (suppose I want the line to made from a column of `*` characters).

How can that be done in Vim or Neovim?

But more generically, is there a way to draw stuff over the text buffer without affecting the text content?

For example, how can I draw an inner rectangle inside a window which I can make bright colored in order to show the active window? The effect would be that the first line visible line of what is currently a text buffer would be filled with `---` characters, the right-most column of the what is currently a text buffer would be filled with `|`. This would be inside the window, separate from the statuslines or vertical split lines.

Etc. How to do such things?

Some plugins that currently draw over the text buffer in different ways:

- https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion
- https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine

Comment: Will `'set colorcolumn=80'` work instead? See `:h 'cc'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EasyMotion does not draw over the text, i don't think this is possible.
What it does is defined in following function [(sourcecode](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion/blob/master/autoload/EasyMotion/helper.vim)):

```
function! EasyMotion#helper#VarReset(var, ...) "{{{
if ! exists('s:var_reset')
    let s:var_reset = {}
endif

if a:0 == 0 && has_key(s:var_reset, a:var)
    " Reset var to original value
    " setbufvar( or bufname): '' or '%' can be used for the current buffer
    call setbufvar('%', a:var, s:var_reset[a:var])
elseif a:0 == 1
    " Save original value and set new var value

    let new_value = a:0 == 1 ? a:1 : ''

    " Store original value
    let s:var_reset[a:var] = getbufvar("", a:var)

    " Set new var value
    call setbufvar('%', a:var, new_value)
endif
endfunction "}}}
```

So it saves every replaced char and restores them afterwards.
I haven't looked at indentLine but it probably does intelligent listchars, as there is never text under the indentchar.

Anyway it isn't as if I am an expert on one of the plugin or vim in general. I just write this answer because i think there are easier way to achieve what you want. You could for example highlight the border lines with a certain color, or change the background for the active split. There is also a plugin for dimming inactive splits: https://github.com/blueyed/vim-diminactive

Comment: I guess I like vim, but wish it was somehow more modern with GUI drawing abilities. Maybe we'll have that in like 20 years.

Comment: I quite like the distraction free appereance of vim. I think most of the time I wish for some GUI capabilities it is, because i use vim wrong (I don't want to say, that is the case in your question), and it takes a lot of time to get used to it, and I still have a long way to go =). But part of the reason is, we are used to so much text editors which are doing things "wrong/not the vim way". If we would have started with vim, it would be perfectly fine.

Comment: True, but there's basic UI styling that a text-based UI simply can not achieve. In a GUI, it is very easy to draw useful things like indent guides (the vim plugins are hacks that don't perform well), minimaps with useful coloring and symbols, and other things that aren't possible in a text-based UI, and that aren't necessarily shortcoming of how one uses Vim. Even if one is a master of Vim, something like a minimap could still be useful for those people who are very visual.

Comment: Some people love hidden buffers, and they aren't visual people, they make mental mappings of their workflow, which is perfectly fine. GUIs simply allow other features not possible in text, even if the user is a ninja at raw text editing in Vim.

Comment: Yeah of course there are advantages in a GUI, it was not my intention to say you are wrong at all. Sorry if I gave you this feeling. I just say, I don't think it will happen even in 20 years, because a lot of the advantages which vim have, will possibly collide with a GUI. The biggest of all, to have the same Enviroment on every system/server you use.